# React Native App crashes after updating Node Version

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have updated my node version, now my react native project is not working I am using react native cli. I have tried uninstalling the other versions of Node and gradlew clean and npm cache clean.

[image: I am attaching error]

Comment: What is the react-native version, and what was your previous node version?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't plan to upgrade your react-native version, downgrade your node version to the one compatible with your project.

Check if node is installed and which version

```
node -v
```

If you often have to switch between node versions you should use a version manager for node like [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) for easy switch.

Comment: I have installed Node 16.13.1 , anyways the problem is loved by reset  node cache.